# Exclude items from view using a filter ("does not contain")

Tags: list-view, filter, sharepoint-views

I know there are several other threads on this topic, but haven't seen anything that would assist with my issue.

Unfortunately I cannot rely on my users to regularly update meta-data (even something as simple as 'status'), but only want current records and draft items to be viewable on the default view.

I didn't think I could rename a Record but hadn't tried until yesterday, which made me think I had a solution - add 'Superseded' to the title and then set a filter to only show items that do not contain superseded in the title. However the 'does not contain' filter isn't an option.

Does anyone know an easy way (one which can be replicated on multiple different sites/libraries) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "Not contains" is not a valid operator in a CAML Query and thus not usable in a list view either.

What you could do is to add a yes/no column called "Superseded" and have a Flow or Workflow (you did not specify what SharePoint environment you are working with) that updates this field whenever an item is changed.
Then, update your view to exclude items that has Superseded = Yes.

Here is an example using Flow:

[image]

The formula I used is:

```
greater(indexOf(toLower(triggerBody()?['{Name}']),'superseded'),0)
```

Which will set the field to Yes if the function (lowercase file name includes 'superseded') equals true.

---

Depending on your environment and document libraries there could be other viable solutions as well.

Comment: thanks. I think this might be over-complicating it...it's probably easier to try and re-educate to using the status column...even if the users aren't updating it properly, if the view is to show all 'blank', 'draft' and 'final' then it will still achieve the same...I'll have to get my staff to keep an eye out for new versions of key documents (which will actually only be in a handful of libraries anyway). Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

In the list settings, create a calculated field.

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND("Superseded",[Title]))
```

You might call this field something like "Calc Is Superseded". The data type returned from this formula is Yes/No.

Then, on your filter, you'll look for records where "Calc Is Superseded" is equal to "No" (without the quotes).